# How to design collections for multi-tenant analytics with MongoDB?

Tags: database-design, mongodb, multi-tenant

I saw several posts regarding multi-tenant approaches with Mongo, but hope I can get more specific feedback for more specific requirements.

Here is what I know from the business side:

- "Free evaluation": should allow free and easy registration of a new tenant (customer); many of them will stay in the system with low activity and volume, and for long.
- Analytics [per tenant] is a key component of the solution. There is no acute need for real-time analytics, and most of it may be done in "batch" processing per tenant.
- Some cross-tenant "internal" analytic processing may also be needed, but at later stages.

I assume that the need for "lightweight" allocation of a new tenant- is not consistent with the "database per tenant" approach.

Assuming I keep separate collections for separate tenants, in the same DB:

- Would it be efficient to schedule so many map-reduce aggregations per each tenant's collections (as opposed to "one big" scan of multi-tenant collections)
- Is there any practical way to perform analytic calculations across multiple collections?
- Are there any other issues with large number of collections, beyond the limit on the total number of collections and indexes? Like, losing support of some libraries and tools designed to work with a fixed collections set?

Alternatively, when managing the "fixed set" multi-tenant collections:

- What are the "best practices" for the collections structure? Should I keep the "tenant document" "by reference" in each and every document within a multi-tenant collection?
- What are the "best practices" to run map-reduce in such a case? Should I try one huge map-reduce, or running multiple map-reduce tasks filtering the collections per tenant?

Thanks,
Max

Comment: why not a db per tenant?

Comment: This blog shows why collection based multi-tenant is more lightweight: http://blog.boxedice.com/2010/02/28/notes-from-a-production-mongodb-deployment/#comment-818